# Show properties of some general function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I've got some function $f : P ( \mathbb{N} ) \rightarrow P(P ( \mathbb{N} ) \times P ( \mathbb{N} ))$

Described as $f(Z) = \{\langle X,Y\rangle: P ( \mathbb{N} )\times P ( \mathbb{N} ) \ \mid Z \subseteq X \cap Y \}$ so $f(Z)$ will give all pairs of sets that each of them at least contains all elements from $Z$.

I managed to prove that $f$ is an injection and $f$ is not a surjection.
But now i'm struggling with inverse image of this function... it is: Show inverse image of set of **all** equivalence relations over $P(\mathbb{N})$ and second, very similiar, Show inverse image of set of **all** partial equivalence relations over $P(\mathbb{N})$
To my understanding i have to give set of sets, in each such set i have to have some numbers. And using all those sets with my function $f$ I should get set of all equivalence relations.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm having hard time proving and coming to right solution, cause it seems so hard...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you want to do. "Show inverse image of set of ... " is not really understandable.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, inverse image of some function $f$, for example $f(x)= x$ for even x and $f(x)= 2*x$ for odd x. 
Now we want to know reverse image of set of even numbers over $\mathbb{N}$, this is... we need to find all values that put as argument will be an even number, so our answer will be set with continous natural numbers. 

In my task, argument of function takes some set over $\mathbb{N}$, right? And the answer has to be all equivalent relations. So we have to find all starting sets that as an answer will give us all equivalent relations ( that's how reverse image works ). Thanks !!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image